# request.user.is_authenticated always returns false

Tags: django, django-authentication

after logging in the user and checking whether request.user isauthenticated in other activity in android. the value is always false.

the following code is used for login a user

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,logout,login


@api_view(['POST'])
def userRegister(request):
    user=User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'],email=request.POST['email'],password=request.POST['password'])
    return Response({'ok':'True'},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

@api_view(['POST'])
def userLogin(request):
    user=authenticate(
        username=request.POST['username'],
        password=request.POST['password']
    )
    if user is not None:
        login(request,user)
        return Response({'ok':'True'},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({'ok':'False'},status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

the following code is used to check whether the user is authenticated or not

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from . import models
from . import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import status


@api_view(['GET'])
def HomeView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return Response(data={"ok":'true'})
    else:
        return Response(data={"ok":"false"})
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?